# Remove everything before the dash from a Laravel array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, sanitization

I have a Laravel array and would like to modify the returned values.

`$array = ['hr-34', 've-53', 'dv-65'];`

I want to remove everything before the dash and the dash itself and return the following array.

`$array = ['34', '53', '65'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to follow:

- define blank array $new_array (to fill single value from foreach loop).
- get single value using foreach loop.
- use [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) for remove everything before dash and remove '-' using [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).
- fill single value in $new_array.
- return $new_array outside foreach loop.

Below is the code -

```
$array = ['hr-34', 've-53', 'dv-65'];

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$result){
    $data = str_replace('-', '', strstr($result, '-'));
    $new_array[]= $data;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode('-', $value);
    $array[$key] = $pieces[1];
}
```

You have used the tag `collections`. So if it's a collection you can use this function:

```
$c->map(function ($item) {
    return explode('-', $item)[1];
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: Then it's not an array like you present it to be. Can you show me what `$c` is?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$array = array_map(function ($item) {
    return explode('-', $item)[1];
}, $array)
```

Edit:
As you changed title from `array` to `collection` you can use:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map

```
$collection->map(...)
```

in a similar way to `array_map(...)`

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: @Elisa That means your array / collection isn't what you provided in question. You can use `dd($collection)` what the values actually are

Answer (score 1):

```php
$array = ['hr-34', 've-53', 'dv-65'];

$array = collect($array)
    ->map(fn($item) => explode('-', $item)[1])
    ->all();

/**
 * array:3 [
 *     0 => "34"
 *     1 => "53"
 *     2 => "65"
 * ]
 */
dd($array);
```

Here this code in [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/vmeli?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=)

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex with `preg_replace` as :

```
$new = array_map(function ($item) {
        return preg_replace('/^([^-])+-/', '', $item);
    }, $array);
```

result :

```
array:3 [
 0 => "34"
 1 => "53"
 2 => "65"
]
```